# Disable quick settings tile in Android

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I cannot find a way to disable **quick settings tile** in Android programmatically that is a requirement for our enterprise launcher.

Are there any clues beyond the [How to disable the notification bar pull-down in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533963/how-to-disable-the-notification-bar-pull-down-in-android) and https://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/android/f/509/t/283260

Is it possible to do? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you want to disable notification bar ?

Comment: You will need to write/create a custom ROM for that

Comment: @Heisen-Berg Well... If will help then yes but actually I need to disable the whole tile with icons like `settings` and all buttons because user is not gonna setup ANY settings only Administrator of the company will do.

Comment: Have you ever heard about MACROS? Implement it for the users which you want to disable it. I think you cannot hide the Android system UI till you don't implement your custom OS, but doing some tricks you can get a success.

Comment: @Akshay Is it possible to catch `Open Settings event` and provide Password Dialog at least? We are tired that our users destroy all settings so we need to protect by blocking user to open `Settings` screen.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid No  i dit not. Please provide  more info and if it will be like a final answer than like an answer. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to hide the statusbar, this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984476/hide-status-bar-in-android-4-4-or-kitkat-with-fullscreen

Comment: You have to access `root` permissions on your device, then you can disable notification bar.

Comment: @Rino the link you provided is app specific..Here the OP wants the device's main status bar to be disabled

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer, yeah I have done some kind of things for one IPTV app, if you really want then I can do a POC for you. Message me @rahul.androidnewsletter@gmail.com for the further discussion.

Comment: Or you can block user to pull down notification bar, while using your application. But as user disable your app, he or she can access notification bar. Or if you want to disable pull down of notification bar for like always, then you just have to set permission like `Apps that can draw over other apps`, after this your app with disabled bar run over on top of every app and user can't access bar.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg It seems your idea is good. Please explain it with more detail slike an answer and I will accept it. Well.. Users will not have any access to `Settings`  because oul launcher will not provide this posibility for them.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid Hey! Thanks, bro. But I have no finance to  firm any contracts like this. Sorry man!

Comment: I am working on your question, I just wanna to ask what's your minimum SDK ?

Comment: @Heisen-Berg Thanks! It is API 23: Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems is impossible to do at all.

That is the answer.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @STiGMa The unique solution is to recompile Android OS source code.

Answer (score 1):

May you start your app in the full screen mode?
like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8470893/2801860

```
<activity
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
  ....
>
```

Comment: Thanks. Well... I did it like `    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                // Full screen mode
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
`  and as says manual here https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/dim.html#dim we cannot hide it absolutly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. I had used the following snippet to disable quick settings.

```
public static void preventStatusBarExpansion(Context context) {
        WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) context.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));



        Activity activity = (Activity)context;
        WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
        localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|

                // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |

                // Draws over status bar
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

        localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int resId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        int result = 0;
        if (resId > 0) {
            result = activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resId);
        }

        localLayoutParams.height = result;

        localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

        customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(context);

        manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
    }
```

Call this method where ever you need. Before calling this method make sure you has screen overlay permission.
However this permission is deprecated in Oreo.

Comment: Thanks, bro! I just vouted up it but will check it a few days later.

Answer (score 0):

No, not impossible. Use ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS to prevent it be pulled down when the screen is locked.