# Restrict Notification Bar from pulling

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, kiosk-mode

```js
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        try{
            if(!hasFocus && enableKioskMode){
                Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
                sendBroadcast(closeDialog);

                ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                am.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);

                // sametime required to close opened notification area
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                    public void run() {
                        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
                        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
                    }
                }, 500);

            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```css
private class CustomViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

        public CustomViewGroup(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

```html
private void addBlockingViews() {

        try {
            WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

            //For Bottom View
            WindowManager.LayoutParams bottomlocalLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            bottomlocalLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;

            bottomlocalLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
            bottomlocalLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            bottomlocalLayoutParams.height = (int) (50 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);

            bottomlocalLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.RGBX_8888;
            bottomlocalLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

            bottomView = new CustomViewGroup(BaseActivity.this);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50);
            bottomView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
            manager.addView(bottomView, bottomlocalLayoutParams);

            WindowManager.LayoutParams toplocalLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            toplocalLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;

            toplocalLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
            int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            int result = 0;
            if (resId > 0) {
                result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resId);
            } else {
                // Use Fallback size:
                result = 60; // 60px Fallback
            }
            //toplocalLayoutParams.height = result;
            toplocalLayoutParams.height = (int) (50 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
            toplocalLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            toplocalLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
            topView = new CustomViewGroup(BaseActivity.this);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    25);
            topView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
            manager.addView(topView, toplocalLayoutParams);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

My aim is to create a Kiosk app. I checked many codes for that like [this](https://github.com/jasondelport/AndroidKioskMode) and [this](http://wenchaojiang.github.io/blog/realise-Android-kiosk-mode/). With their help I have achieved navigation bar hiding. Now I want to block user from dragging the notification bar down just like Surelock does. I've tried the common answers given in SO posts like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533963/how-to-disable-the-notification-bar-pull-down-in-android). But it does not work in my Redmi Note 5 Pro with Android Pie. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: can you post the code that you've tried so far

Comment: @ManojPerumarath sure.

Comment: @ManojPerumarath I added my code. It includes the usual CustomViewGroup blocking class. But it doesn't restrict anything. I found that `onWindowFocusChanged()` could be used but it also not working.

Comment: You can use that code till Lollipop `api 22` after that use the solution recommended by `bwt`, any way you need your app as admin  @Somnath Pal

Comment: That's not the proper solution. Please check Surelock. That does not require the device to be admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution notification bar is not blocked entirely but it gets closed after user opens it. You need a service that checks if the notification bar is open repeatedly. This service uses reflection to get needed method to close the notification bar after it gets opened so I think it wont work on android 9 devices(just checked it working fine with compilesdk 28 on a 7.1.1 device). you need to use this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
```

this is the code for the service:

```
public class CollapseService extends Service {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable(this);

        scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate
                (runnable, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private void collapseNow() {
        Object statusBarService = getSystemService("statusbar");
        Class<?> statusBarManager = null;

        try {
            statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Method collapseStatusBar = null;

        try {
            collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        collapseStatusBar.setAccessible(true);

        try {
            collapseStatusBar.invoke(statusBarService);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }

    static class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
        CollapseService aService = null;
        MyRunnable(CollapseService service){
            WeakReference<CollapseService> weakReference = new WeakReference<>(service);
            aService = weakReference.get();
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            if(aService != null) {
                aService.collapseNow();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Weak reference is to remove the possibility of occurrence of memory leaks.

Comment: I would say its working in Android Pie. I'll still check in other android versions just to be sure. If successful, I'll accept your answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If your kiosk app is a device owner (as explained in one of your referenced examples) you can use [`DevicePolicyManager.setStatusBarDisabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setStatusBarDisabled(android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean)) :

> Disabling the status bar blocks notifications, quick settings and
>   other screen overlays that allow escaping from a single use device.

It is available since Android 6 (API 23), the status bar is still displayed (with the time, wifi level, bluetooth indicator, ...) but the notifications are not and you cannot expand it.

Comment: No. My app is not device owner. As I checked that to make a device owner, you have to remove any Google a/c association and then install the app. That is not my case.

Comment: I only used it in device owner apps, but the API says that the method can also be used by a profile owner app

Comment: I checked this. First it requires API 23 but app's minSDk is 22. Also it requires the app to be device owner.

Comment: I is a bit strange, the whole point of a profile owner is to allow users to bring their own device. But anyway, it will not work with API 22.

Comment: Is there any other way for API 22 and below?

Comment: Unfortunately, all the solutions I have ever seen are hacks, they may work if you can control the device / Android, but are not robust / durable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196817/discussion-between-somnath-pal-and-bwt).