# Disable android status bar to expand

Tags: android, statusbar

Actually, I'm trying to develop an android app that will be used only on our store. The user should use only this app and nothing else.

I have already create an activity that start on fullscreen, so we can't see the action bar and the status bar.

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

But the problem is, that the users (crafty one) know that they can open the settings menu from wifi option and close my app or even uninstall it.

How can I disable/hide the status bar to expand ? or either disable the access to the settings menu from the status bar ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing status bar expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457730/preventing-status-bar-expansion)

Comment: It's already answered.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920052/disable-the-notification-panel-from-being-pulled-down

Comment: @Henshaw Sorry, but it doesn't really work as I want