# Full screen pull down disabling

Tags: android, statusbar

I'm developing an `full screen application` but it's possible for the user to pull down the status bar, and after, access to wifi, bluetooth... features. I have watched some applications that have a complete full screen and don't allow pull down the status bar. The only aproximation is collapse it but this solution allow the user to access all these features. This is the aproximation that isn't is valid for me:

```
                   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                        collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager
                                .getMethod("collapsePanels");
                    } else {
                        collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager
                                .getMethod("collapse");
                    }
```

Comment: Its simple. if you want to permanently hide status bar in Android 4.0 and lower, set full screen theme in manifest.

Comment: Isn't that a feature added with kk? I don't think you can just go and disable it.

Comment: The issue is i have Android 4.4.2 version and the app is only for this API version

Answer (score 1):

Check it

```
     this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // Remove title bar
     this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);// Remove notification bar
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

Comment: I have tested this solution but it is still possible to show status bar pulling down in the top of the screen. I need the user cannot show any bar.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920052/disable-the-notification-panel-from-being-pulled-down) These are ths codes i have tested but the user can still drag down status bar. The only thing i have got is collapse notifications panel when it is opened.