# Disable top swipe android

Tags: java, android, service, swipe

i know there is several post talking about swipe, but didnt find any about what im trying to do.

I am trying to disable (so i dont want to see it at all), the top swipe notification within a service. So it disable it on every application possible.

Actually the only thing i successed to do is to make it scrollback everytime it get openned. But if you are a bit skilled , you can lock it open.

--

Quick briefing : My service must disable the top swipe.

--

I tried the mDrawer LOCKED_CLOSED thing, but wont work, and plus it wont work within a service.

--

Thanks for you help.

Comment: i found the solution , thanks to @ZZeyaNN , from http://stackoverflow.com/a/32392567/4385012