# On Android how can you detect when a user opens the system notification drawer?

Tags: java, android

On Android how can you detect when the user opens the system notification drawer?  I've not found which calls are required to do this or even if it's possible?  Does it cause a system notification I can monitor for?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question in another SO question...

[Disable the notification panel from being pulled down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920052/disable-the-notification-panel-from-being-pulled-down)

It's a different issue but the ways for responding to changes in behaviour of the status bar/notification drawer is what I wanted.  What I was looking for was responding to `onWindowFocusChanged` as well adding the `uses-permission` line to the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private DrawerLayout drawer_layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    drawer_layout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_drawer_layout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer_layout, "open", "close");
    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    // ...
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "drawer opened");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think he means the top level system notification bar.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake. I leave the answer just in case it is useful to someone.

Comment: Yes @Deev system notification bar.  Thanks. I've edited the title and contents to denote this.  Thanks for the response anyways Sergio.