# Disable/Ask for password before showing top&bottom nav bar

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-windowmanager, android-immersive

While developing a client survey app for a tablet I realized I have to disable the notification panel from being pulled & hide bottom navigation just in case, for all those *funny* clients out there trying to be a smart ***.

I am working with a non rooted device so using a reflection like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008799/3987406) answer isn't an option.

> And while adding
>   `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY);`
>   will do the trick, it will also disable everything else.

---

I started by requesting full screen for the app just to hide the top bar but this didn't do anything to the bottom navigation bar.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Therefore I resorted to using [Immersive Full-Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html). It does hide both top and bottom bars but when the user swipes up or down, they appear again.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

---

> *The device runs on **Android 4.4***

## I am looking for a way to completely disable them or (*best case scenario*) **ask for a password before showing them again**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your problem, what you are looking for is a single purpose device and you can achieve what you want using the `startLockTask()` function if the device is running Android 5 and higher as said here https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html#emm-solutions

> The device owner must include your app’s package(s) in setLockTaskPackages
>   Sets the packages that can enter into lock task mode
>   Needs to be set by the EMM
>   You can call isLockTaskPermitted to verify that your package has been whitelisted by setLockTaskPackages.
>   Your activity calls `startLockTask()`
>   Requests to lock the user into the current task
>   Prevents launching other apps, settings, and the Home button
>   To exit, your activity must call `stopLockTask()`
>   Can only be called on an activity that’s previously called `startLockTask()`
>   Should be called when the app is user-facing between `onResume()` and `onPause()`

It seems that you can achieve the same things on Android versions lower than 5 by using these actions as said here: http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

> Overview
>
> A Kiosk Mode is implemented by disabling various Android
>   features that can be used to leave your app. The following features
>   are affected:
>
> - The back button
> - The home button
> - The recent apps button
> - The power button
> - The volume buttons

Comment: Sounds just about right. I'm reading the guide right now and trying to figure our if their device supports lock task. I'll return with feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Apparently this was introduced since android 5 but the the device I am working on has android 4.4 on it.

Comment: Thank you! I am accepting your answer and awarding you the bounty cause of the link you posted! It really helped me a lot. I will add another answer with my complete solution.

Comment: Great! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably more work than you want, but you could develop a custom launcher to prevent exiting the survey application, or immediately re-launch it on exit Launcher in this case being the default home screen and activity launching interface... That would at least work on lover versions of Android. I would expect it to be quite a lot of work though, especially to "plug" all the little get-arounds and holes that your users might find (getting into the settings etc)