# Notification swipe down panel disable for whole project from xml

Tags: android, system-tray

I just working with one of project having requirement of `disabling swipe down notification tray`.

actually, I have a bunch of activities around 30+ so I don't want to make a **redundant code**.

I check some links      but having to much code.
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008799/3513479)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482868/3513479)

So My simple Question is How To disable notification panel from **style** directly ?
because i cant find any style code for `SYSTEM_OVERLAY` in xml.

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: why don't you try to hide notification bar and make it full screen ?

Comment: As per requirement, some time client cant understand and we have to force do like as they said. @Radhey