# How to disable pull down the status bar in android programmatically

Tags: java, android, statusbar

I have tried several options to disable the pulling down of status bar.

Option one:

```
  //call this method in onWindowFocusChanged()
  public void collapseNow(){
    // Initialize 'collapseNotificationHandler'
    if (collapseNotificationHandler == null) {
        collapseNotificationHandler = new Handler();
    }
    // If window focus has been lost && activity is not in a paused state
    // Its a valid check because showing of notification panel
    // steals the focus from current activity's window, but does not
    // 'pause' the activity
    if (!currentFocus && !isPaused) {

        // Post a Runnable with some delay - currently set to 300 ms
        collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Use reflection to trigger a method from 'StatusBarManager'

                @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") Object statusBarService = getSystemService("statusbar");
                Class<?> statusBarManager = null;

                try {
                    statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Method collapseStatusBar = null;

                try {

                    // Prior to API 17, the method to call is 'collapse()'
                    // API 17 onwards, the method to call is `collapsePanels()`

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                        collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
                    } else {
                        collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                    }

                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                collapseStatusBar.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    collapseStatusBar.invoke(statusBarService);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Check if the window focus has been returned
                // If it hasn't been returned, post this Runnable again
                // Currently, the delay is 100 ms. You can change this
                // value to suit your needs.
                if (!currentFocus && !isPaused) {
                    collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100L);
                }

            }
        }, 300L);
    }
}
```

Using this solution user can still able to pull down but it will automatically pull up.

Option 2:

```
public void preventStatusBarExpansion(Context context) {
 WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(MainActivity.this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
        }
    }
    WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
    localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|

            // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |

            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |

            // Draws over status bar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

    localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    localLayoutParams.height = (int) (50 * getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
    localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

    CustomViewGroup view = new CustomViewGroup(this);

    manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);

}
```

This solution does not work as its still showing the status bar and user can able to access it.

Option 3:

```
 private void hideSystemUi() {

        // hide status bar
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

}
```

I have tried all the options available but none of them are working, first time the status bar wont be visible but once user clicks on the status bar it will visible and I don't want this to happen.
Please help if you have achieve to disable pulling down the status bar functionality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable the notification panel from being pulled down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920052/disable-the-notification-panel-from-being-pulled-down)